# Forked repo workflow, when visibility of upstream changed from private to public

Tags: git, github

Recently I was working on a private repo, I have forked that repo and started working on that project(creating PR etc.). Now the owner has changed the visibility of upstream repo from `private -> public`.
Now this repo exist as private repo in my local git/Github. I was trying to figure out how to attach that repo again to upstream public repo. I found only way of doing this by deleting private repo in my account and then fork public repo again.

Is there any better way to do this or this is the only way people do, are there any suggested steps from git ?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility#changing-a-private-repository-to-a-public-repository

Comment: After making your repository public contact support and ask them to reattach you repository as a fork of the upstream.

Answer (score 0):

> **Changing a private repository to a public repository**
>
> If a private repository is made public, each of its private forks is
> turned into a standalone private repository and becomes the parent of
> its own new repository network. ***Private forks are never automatically
> made public*** because they could contain sensitive commits that
> shouldn't be exposed publicly.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility#changing-a-private-repository-to-a-public-repository

You can:

1. backup private repo (r)
2. delete private repo
3. fork again
4. create your own branch (b)
5. use [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/) to compare, then merge (physcially) from (r) to (b)